# How to stop QnAMaker dialog from returning to parent dialog?

Tags: node.js, botframework

Trying to understand MS Bot Framework and build my first bot.

The default dialog is a `Prompts.choice`. First choice passes to new dialog that asks for `Prompts.text`.

User enters text which then passes that to my QnAMaker, which looks for the answer and returns it. This works as expected.

After answer is returned, my bot closes the QnAMaker dialog and then returns to the default dialog where the bot starts over from the beginning. **I don't want this to happen.**

How do I keep the user in the QnAMaker dialog so that they can continually ask QNAMaker questions until they are done and want to do something else in the bot?

Screenshot of terminal output. Code below. Thanks!

[image]

```
    bot.dialog('rentalHelp', [
  function(session) {
    builder.Prompts.text(session, "In which state do you live? (please spell out)");
  },
  function(session, results) {
    // start the QnA bot dialog
    session.beginDialog('QnAMaker');
  }
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured out the reason it was doing this from [Bot SDK chat reference library](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/node/builder/chat-reference/interfaces/_botbuilder_d_.idialogwaterfallstep.html)

Excerpt:

> note: Waterfalls have a hidden last step which will automatically end the current dialog if if you call a prompt or dialog from the last step. This is useful where you have a deep stack of dialogs and want a call to session.endDialog() from the last child on the stack to end the entire stack. The close of the last child will trigger all of its parents to move to this hidden step which will cascade the close all the way up the stack. This is typically a desired behavior but if you want to avoid it or stop it somewhere in the middle you'll need to add a step to the end of your waterfall that either does nothing or calls something like session.send() which isn't going to advance the waterfall forward.

It would be great if someone could confirm this is the problem or help me to improve my code.